# Webpack cannot resolve object require

Tags: javascript, arrays, module, webpack, require

I'm building a webapp and i need webpack to require an object in a config file up one folder.

```
└─ config.js
└─ foo
   └─bar.js
```

let's say that `bar.js` needs to get a `kitty` const in config.js

At the moment my code look like this in `config.js` javascript

```
const kitty = {
    meow: {
        'name': "prrr",
    }
};
```

and like this in `bar.js` javascript

```
require('../config')
console.log(kitty.meow.name)
```

but I'm returning an error that says

```
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../config
```

Comment: Can you modify your file structure to include the webpack config and where it is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using es6 syntax

```
export const kitty = {...}
```

and

```
import kitty from '../config.js'
```